# Force ros diagnostic_updater to publish on other topics

Tags: ros

I am using the ros diagnostic_updater class (http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostic_updater) to publish diagnostic messages and found that it publishes to /diagnostics by default. Is there any way to force it to publish to another topic instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any ROS node you can make use of a the `remap` tag in a `roslaunch` file. For example this will remap the topic to `/some_new_topic`:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="diagnostic_updater" type="diagnostic_updater" name="diagnostic_updater" output="screen">
    <remap from="diagnostics" to="/some_new_topic" />
  </node>
</launch>
```